# jQuery pass event on to underlying element

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I have an image with a click event bound to it which grows/shrinks the image. I am using jQuery to place a magnifying glass in the top corner of the image. The problem is that clicking on the magnifying glass doesn't trigger the image's grow/shrink. Is there a jQuery way to pass the click on to the underlying element or to have the image subscribe to the magnifying glass's click event?

I know that I can put a click handler on the magnifying glass and have it trigger the image's click event, but I want to know if there is another, better way of doing this.

In response to comments my general HTML is:

```
<div style="position: relative">
   <img src="growme.jpg" />
   <img src="magnify.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0;" />
</div>
```

and Pseudo-code for jQuery

```
$(growme).load(
   $(growme).parent().append($(magnify));
   $(growme).click(...);
)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two in the DOM? Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @lonesomeday added psuedo code and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorted this one out on my own. I can use jQuery's .live() which will automatically bind events when elements are added. So I just call in my (document).ready and every time a magnifying glass is added I can have it click the previous element (my image) for me.

```
jQuery(".magnify").live("click", function() {
     jQuery(this).prev().click();
});
```

Comment: I think you have a typo -- this will bind a click event to any `<magnify>` HTML tags, now or in the future.

Comment: thanks yc. just pseudocode, but I added in a '.' just so that other SO'ers won't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

> ...have the image subscribe to the
>   magnifying glass's click event?

Instead of having $('#image').click(...), do $('#image, #image .magnify').click().

Comment: this seems like a good idea. right now in the images .load event I call $(this).click and bind my click event. So it seems I would want to do something like $(this, $(this).next()).click. Not sure if that is valid code though.

Comment: hmmm. not working out so well. the click event needs to belong to the underlying image because that is what is being resized, not the magnifying glass which is .next. I need a click on the magnifying glass to call the click event of the underlying image.

Comment: could wrap the image and the magnify in a div.whatever, and click event function could compensate for either by doing something like $(this).closest('div.whatever').find('img:first')

Comment: good suggestion. i think this would work, I ended up coming up with my own solution though.